# gpt4all chat service session manager

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chat, gpt4all

below is the Python code for using the GPT4All `chat_session` context manager to maintain chat conversations with the model.

```
model = GPT4All(model_name='orca-mini-3b-gguf2-q4_0.gguf')  
with model.chat_session():     
    response1 = model.generate(prompt='hello', temp=0)     
    response2 = model.generate(prompt='write me a short poem', temp=0)     
    response3 = model.generate(prompt='thank you', temp=0)         
    print(model.current_chat_session)`
```

But when my back-end service uses this code, a new session will be opened for each front-end call. The WITH code block returns a contextmanager. The current session will be closed every time the code runs. It is impossible to achieve multiple calls to the front-end at the same time. In a session, to maintain the contextual coherence of AI chat

I want to implement an AI chat backend service using gpt4all, where multiple calls in the same session can maintain contextual coherence, making the conversation complete. Could you help me optimize the content within the `with` block to ensure that the frontend remains within the same session during calls?